# Installing pygame on a mac without Homebrew or MacPorts

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to get pygame on my MacBook Pro without having to install HomeBrew or MacPorts. Basically I am trying to get it installed without any 3rd party software. I have searched around but all I could find was about installing it with HomeBrew or MacPorts.

So here I ask how can I install pygame on a MacBook Pro without having to use/install Homebrew or MacPorts? I have both the pre installed python 2.7 and I installed python 3.5 straight from the python website (I would prefer to be able to use python 3 with pygame). I have Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite) and standard MacBook Pro hardware. I have already installed Xcode 6.

If possible, I would prefer that the question be answered like this...

1. Is installing pygame on a mac without MacPorts or HomeBrew possible?
2. If so how can I? If not possible don't answer this one.
3. Which download from their site should I choose (there are lots of them)
4. If I do it like this will I be able to use python 3 with it
5. If there is anything else I will need to do or install please list them here.

I know there is a lot to this question but all help with this issue would be appreciated. Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the dmg file, you can find that here.

http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

Otherwise, you may be able to install it through `pip`, but you'd need mercurial/git (according to the sources I found)